# Run Spring boot App using docker container and nginx

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jsp, nginx

I trying to open JSP files using docker containers and nginx server. I run spring boot app by making it as a container. But when I try to open `http://152.18.5.150:8081/hello`  page it cannot find root path. 
My **app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD jarfolder/docker-spring-controller.jar docker-spring-controller.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/docker-spring-controller.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: some-nginx-control
    image: nginx:1.13
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
  db:
    restart: always
    container_name: docker-postgresql_2
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=abdu
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

**/nginx/conf.d/app.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log off;


    location ~ \.jsp$ {
        root app/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /hello {
        proxy_pass http://app:8081/hello;
    }

    location /static {
        access_log   off;
        expires      30d;

        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.port=8081
```

**MyController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome_page() { //ModelMap map

    return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello_page() { //ModelMap map

        return "hello";
    }

}
```

when i run command `docker ps -a`

```
IMAGE                              PORTS
nginx:1.13                       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
docker-spring-controller_app     0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp
```

`.jsp` files are app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/

Please help me. Where I am making mistake

Comment: Hi. Sometimes people forget to properly package their applications, when building jars and since only launch in ide, forget about it, have you verified that your jar indeed contains required files?

Comment: I think there is no problem with jar files. Maybe mistake is related with nginx.conf files

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: How do you package as a jar although you are using jsp? It should be war file , shouldn’t it?